# Unusual characters while printing after using ReadFile

Tags: c, winapi, readfile

I have a simple text file that has `"SakyLabs. Hello, MDE"`, and I am trying to reading it using `ReadFile` function and then printing out, but I am getting:

```
?SakyLabs. Hello, MDE??²
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
    // For CreateFileW
    HANDLE createFile;  
    DWORD fileDesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
    DWORD fileShareMode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
    DWORD creationDisposition = CREATE_ALWAYS;
    DWORD fileFlags = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;

    // ReadFile function
    BOOL readFile;
    DWORD lastError;
    DWORD fileSize;
    LPWSTR fileBuffer;
    DWORD bytesRead;

    if ((wcscmp(argv[1], L"-ef") == 0))
    {
        createFile = CreateFileW(argv[2], fileDesiredAccess, fileShareMode, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, fileFlags, NULL);

        // To get extended error message 
        lastError = GetLastError();

        if (createFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            wprintf(L"Error %d opening the file: ", lastError);
            ShowErrorMessage(lastError);
            return;
        }

        // File was opened! Let's read it's content

        fileSize = GetFileSize(createFile, NULL);

        fileBuffer = (LPWSTR)malloc((fileSize) + 1);

        if (fileBuffer == NULL)
        {
            wprintf(L"Could not allocated memory.\n");
            CloseHandle(createFile);
            return;
        }

        readFile = ReadFile(createFile, fileBuffer, fileSize, &bytesRead, NULL);
        lastError = GetLastError();

        if (!readFile)
        {
            wprintf(L"Error code %d reading the file:  ", lastError);
            ShowErrorMessage(lastError);
            CloseHandle(createFile);
            return;
        }

        fileBuffer[fileSize] = '\0';

        // Show the content
        wprintf(L"%s \n", fileBuffer);
        free(fileBuffer);
        CloseHandle(createFile);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) `fileBuffer[fileSize]` uses a byte index for a `wchar_t` array, which will be a buffer overflow. (2) Use a debugger to look at the numeric values in the buffer before you print them. Maybe it's a UTF-16LE BOM.

Comment: Please review the answer to your previous wchar question. The fact that you run into the same problem as when you were trying to write to the file, means that you blindly applied the suggested fix without trying to understand what was wrong with your code. We aren't here to write your code for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't want you to write my code, and I don't understand how this is similar to my previous question. Here I am trying to print and don't understand what the problem is. Also, the only way, I think, to learn is by coding and failing. I don't want to bother you or any other experts here. Appreciate your help in previous questions.

Comment: @SergioCalderon this question and your previous question both suffer from a common problem - you don't seem to understand the difference between a **single** byte and a **multi-byte** character, so you are making mistakes using one in place of the other. A `wchar_t` is 2 bytes in size on Windows (4 bytes on other platforms), but Win32 file I/O APIs operate on bytes not characters.

Comment: Change `fileBuffer[fileSize] = '\0';` to `fileBuffer[] = L'\0';` (or `fileBuffer[fileSize / sizeof(*fileBuffer)] = L'\0';`) Alternatively, you don't have to terminate the array at all if you give the size to `wprintf()` instead, eg: `wprintf(L"%.*s \n", (int)(fileSize / sizeof(WCHAR)), fileBuffer);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for answering again. If yo want, please post the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @SergioCalderon answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
fileBuffer[fileSize] = '\0';
```

`fileSize` is expressed in raw bytes, but `fileBuffer` is an array of `WCHAR` elements, where `WCHAR` is 2 bytes in size. As such, you end up writing *way* past the end of the array into surrounding memory, which is *undefined behavior*.

Put another way, your file is 40 bytes in size, and you are allocating `40+1` bytes for your array. That array can hold a max of 20 `WCHAR`s, which means its valid indexes are `0..19`, but since you are using `fileSize` as an index, you are writing the `'\0'` to the `WCHAR` located at index 40.

To fix that, you need to change this:

```
fileBuffer = (LPWSTR)malloc((fileSize) + 1);
...
fileBuffer[fileSize] = '\0';
```

To this instead:

```
fileBuffer = (LPWSTR)malloc(fileSize + sizeof(WCHAR));
...
fileBuffer[fileSize / sizeof(WCHAR)] = L'\0';
```

Now it will write the `L'\0'` into index 20, which is the array element that `+sizeof(WCHAR)` is allocating space for.

Alternatively, you don't have to null-terminate the array at all, if you instead tell `wprintf()` how many `WCHAR`s to print, eg:

```
wprintf(L"%.*s \n", (int)(fileSize / sizeof(WCHAR)), fileBuffer);
```

---

On a side note -

Your code is not checking if `GetFileSize()` failed before using `fileSize`.

Also, when calling `ReadFile()`, `fileSize` is the *requested* number of bytes to read, but `bytesRead` receives the number of bytes *actually* read. `ReadFile()` *can* return fewer bytes than requested.  So, you should use `bytesRead` instead of `fileSize` when terminating/printing `fileBuffer`.  Otherwise, call `ReadFile()` in a loop to ensure *all* of the required bytes are actually read.

And, you are leaking `fileBuffer` if `ReadFile()` fails.

Answer (score -2):

1.You should initialize the buffer `fileBuffer`.
2.`fileBuffer` size should be `fileSize`+2.
3.`FF FE` is the leading BOM.

> If the 16-bit units use little-endian order ("UTF-16LE"), the BOM is
> the (hexadecimal) byte sequence FF FE

[image]
[image]

Update the revised code:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<wchar.h>

int main()
{
    // For CreateFileW
    HANDLE createFile;
    DWORD fileDesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
    DWORD fileShareMode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
    DWORD creationDisposition = CREATE_ALWAYS;
    DWORD fileFlags = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;

    // ReadFile function
    BOOL readFile;
    DWORD lastError;
    DWORD fileSize;
    LPWSTR fileBuffer;
    DWORD bytesRead;

    {

        createFile = CreateFileW(L"Test.txt", fileDesiredAccess, fileShareMode, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, fileFlags, NULL);

        // To get extended error message 
        lastError = GetLastError();

        if (createFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            wprintf(L"Error %d opening the file: ", lastError);
            return 0;
        }

        // File was opened! Let's read it's content

        fileSize = GetFileSize(createFile, NULL);

        fileBuffer = (LPWSTR)malloc((fileSize)+2);

        if (fileBuffer == NULL)
        {
            wprintf(L"Could not allocated memory.\n");
            CloseHandle(createFile);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            memset(fileBuffer,0, (fileSize)+2);
        }

        readFile = ReadFile(createFile, fileBuffer, fileSize, &bytesRead, NULL);
        lastError = GetLastError();

        if (!readFile)
        {
            wprintf(L"Error code %d reading the file:  ", lastError);
            CloseHandle(createFile);
            return 0;
        }

        //fileBuffer[fileSize] = '\0';

        // Show the content
        wprintf(L"%s \n", fileBuffer+1);
        free(fileBuffer);
        CloseHandle(createFile);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Updated the revised code.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I changed the project properties to Multi-Byte Characters and worked.

Comment: @SergioCalderon Setting the character encoding to *"Multi-Byte"* is not a solution to any problem. Indeed, relying on this setting is questionable already.